# Calling invoice number and customer email on success.phtml

Tags: magento, tracking, review

I need to call the invoice number and customer email on magento success.phtml grammatically.

I need this for pre-populated email for resellerrating exit survey code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.resellerratings.com/images
/js/dhtml_survey.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
seller_id =  XXXX;
inv = "B5000";
email_pass = "customer@someplace.com";
document.write('<'+ 'script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.resellerratings.com/images/js/popup_include.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

I know how to call the order ID and Grandtotal:

```
     $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId());
     $amount = number_format($order->getGrandTotal(),2);
```

I found this code somewhere on magento forums, but have no idea how to call out the invoice number and customer email for resellerratings. Help me out with this please.

Regards, 
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();`

Will have a lot of data you need about the current customer.

Re: Invoicing: are you generating invoices as the orders are placed?

An order can have multiple invoices, and multiple invoice IDs.

Check out this post for an example of how to get the Invoice IDs: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/198222/#t313532

Comment: Thanks for help djdy. Appreciate it a lot. 

I must put this code snippet above the resellerratings code right? but how to I alter the resellerratings code itself? Can you help me with modifying the reselleratings code itself please? 

    I found the code in the link you gave me, I will include that code too in my success.phtml but I have no idea what to write in the resellerratings code instead of


    inv = "B5000"; << Instead of  B5000 

or "customer@someplace.com" on the email_pass field.

Thanks again : ))

Comment: Is resellerratings a third party extension?

Comment: resellerratings is not really an extension, its a third party website that gathers reviews and displays them in google shopping and other websites. The code that resellerratings provides is posted above in my question. I was able to input the invoice number correctly, now Im having a problem with email_pass variable : ((

Thanks again for help djdy. I really appreciate it. God bless...

Comment: @JonathanBell I'm sorry I am not familiar with resellersrating. Does email_pass come from the customer? Is it a custom attribute or just an e-mail? Try looking on the customer object, perhaps after getData, just to see if it might be in it.

Comment: Will post here if I'll have a working solution after tests. email_pass is the email of customer who made an order. You're sorry? : )) I appreciate your help anyways djdy, Thanks a lot! I think Im going to a good direction with your hints now.

Answer (score 1):

First, add an event observer code in your module config.xml /your_module/etc/config.xml,

```
<global> 
  <events>
    <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
      <observers>
        <your_module>
          <type>singleton</type>
          <class>your_module/observer</class>
          <method>sales_order_invoice_save_after</method>
        </your_module>
      </observers>
    </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
  </events>
</global>
```

then, add an event observer in your `Observer.php` /your_module/model/Observer.php

```
Class NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer()
{  
    public function sales_order_invoice_save_after($observer)
    // here should be save_after because invoice id  not available until the object has been saved that means an order
    {  
        $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice(); 
        // to see what variables available in $invoice, use the following
        // echo "<pre>"; print_r($invoice->getData()); exit;
    }
}
```